# How to prevent tracing content from components in a TraceListener?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, tracelistener

I am using SMO (added to my project using the NuGet package named Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects - version 160.200421.0) and noticed that all of a sudden, my logs are filled with tracing from that library which is being way too verbose!

For example, this code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string strServerName = @"private";
            string strScriptDatabaseName = "private";
            string strUid = "private";
            string strPwd = "private";

            Server _objServer = new Server();
            _objServer.ConnectionContext.ServerInstance = strServerName;
            _objServer.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure = false;
            _objServer.ConnectionContext.Login = strUid;
            _objServer.ConnectionContext.Password = strPwd;
            Trace.WriteLine("before Connect", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"));
            _objServer.ConnectionContext.Connect();
            Trace.WriteLine("after Connect", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"));

            Trace.WriteLine($"before Databases", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"));
            Database _objDatabase = _objServer.Databases[strScriptDatabaseName];
            Trace.WriteLine($"after Databases", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"));
        }
    }
}
```

Generates these lines in my Ouput Window:

1. 2020-05-26 10:33:26: before Databases 'WindowsFormsApp1.exe' (CLR
   v4.0.30319: WindowsFormsApp1.exe): Loaded
2. WindowsFormsApp1.exe Information: 0 : 2020-05-26T10:33:27.5115418-04:00 - get data for
       urn: Server/Database[@Name='master']
3. WindowsFormsApp1.exe Information: 0 : 2020-05-26T10:33:27.6665197-04:00 - get data for
           urn: Server[@Name='XXXXXXXXXXXX']/Database[@Name='Maintenace']
4. WindowsFormsApp1.exe Information: 0 : 2020-05-26T10:33:27.7045275-04:00 - Failed to Initialize urn
           Server[@Name='XXXXXXXXX']/Database[@Name='Maintenace']
5. 2020-05-26 10:33:31: after Databases

And since I do log using a TraceListener, the 3 lines between my 2 Trace.WriteLine are also getting into my logs and I don't want them. Other operations from the same library are generating 100s of rows making my logs unreadable and useless.

How to prevent the tracing from catching these rows? I don't want these rows to reach my logs.

Comment: The trace level is probably set to verbose (4) which is including everything.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/how-to-create-initialize-and-configure-trace-switches?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: as you can see on the output, the level returned by SMO is Information. I can't set it lower then Information without a lot of recoding. I need a solution that will let me ignore the diagnostics of other components like SMO.

Comment: Follow instructions to turn INFO to OFF.  Then create you own Trace Name and Turn it on.

Comment: Or is there a trick to move all my tracing to my own trace name without literally modify thousands of lines of code?

Comment: Found something interesting. I reverted to the previous version of the SMO NuGet package and don't have the log full of crap anymore. But my real issue is still not solved. How can we filter out what goes through diagnostics tracing?